# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find verticle:

Tags: vert.x

I have installed vertx and when trying to run a test file according to the manual http://vertx.io/core_manual_ruby.html#writing-verticles
i am getting the below error.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find verticle: /var/www/pykih/server.rb

Whatm am i missing?

Comment: Problem resolved. cannot pass the entire path in vertx command. Instead first have to go to the path and then just pass the filename in vertex command.

Comment: you got it. I wrote a little standard install guide (mostly for myself) as I setup production boxes. I plan on adding OS and tuning tricks to the guide too. http://rick-hightower.blogspot.com/2013/11/installing-vertx-on-ubuntu-13.html